# Similar UI for iOS and .Net

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, ios, user-interface

I am writing an app whose functional requirements target iPad and Windows Tab. I want to design a uniform UI across both the platforms.

I thought of using HTML5 as a method to create same UI, but it is not working well with other requirements.

I need suggestions and ideas for solving this problem?

Comment: It's like adding a Windows-style task bar in XMB: better recreate the UI for every platform conforming that platform's interface guidelines.

Comment: GUI design is not a problem about executable or not. It's a problem about look & feel. It's about a natural harmony. Of course if we don't have to care about quality of user's experience, this doesn't matter. Use anything like `Adobe Air`.

Comment: Finally figured the way out of problem using HTML5 and CSS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has solved the problem using HTML5 and CSS3. I designed the required pages in HTML5 and used UIWebView in iOS and Web Browser control in .Net to display them. It reduced the UI differences by a large scale.

Answer (score 5):

Cross platform apps look alien on all machines they are running on.

If you want to create a good user experience then try to stick to the same navigation / interaction scheme, use similar graphics but try to adhere to each platforms guidelines.

[Opera](http://www.opera.com/) for example is (my opinion) a good sample. They are keeping their unique style but the application behaves and looks like native a native app on each OS.

Comment: Another good example is uTorrent for Windows and Mac, and a bad example is Inkscape.

Comment: Finally figured the way out of problem using HTML5 and CSS3.